# CMOD 755 is not possible

Tags: file-permissions, chmod

If CMOD 755 is not possible and 767 is not either, what is the next best permission? So far I have checked 775 and it works, but is it safe? It is an upload directory and the only people uploading to it are a select few of admins (ie not worries with them).

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a several users in the same group that need to write the directory, then yiou want 770 or 775.  (Which should apply to your admins.)  Use 770 if you only want the group to be able to read the directory.  If you want all users to be able to read the directory use 775.  Chgrp the directory to a group that only the admins belong to.

Comment: BillThor is correct. If you only want people in a select group to access the directory then the last number - the "world" - should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

767 seems odd. is that person RWX, Group RW, anyoen RWX. That doesn't seem like it would work because everyone has higher permissions than your group.

Im assuming your talking 
1) about a directory in which case execute means search
2) that all these admins are seperate users but in the same group.

in which case
775 might be what you want.

You read/write/search dir
You freinds read/write/search dir
everyone else can only read/search dir.